# Getting the last characters of a string

Tags: python, string

So, I have a string, for example:

```
string = '34567'
```

I know that string[-1] will return me '7', but how do I get like '567'? Because it doesn't work if I start from the middle:

```
string[2:-1] == '56'
```

Usually, since the last number doesn't count, you just add 1 to it, but in this case you can't do it

So how do I print '567'?

Comment: it's `string[2:]`, more details in the dupe.

Answer (score 0):

> but in this case you can't do it

You can by not providing it.

```
>>> '34567'[-3:]
'567'
```

Which basically asks for "the last 3 characters of the string"

Answer (score 0):

To get the last 3 characters of a string you slice this way:

```
string[-3:]
```